# Link components to own Navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, navbar

I build my own `Navbar` using a YT-Tutorial and now I'm trying to connect the different sections of the website using `react-router-dom`. But when I click the `Navbar` in the browser it shows nothing, I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Blog from './components/Blog/Blog'
import About from './components/About/About'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/components/Home/Home' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/components/Blog/Blog' component={Blog} />
          <Route path='/components/About/About' component={About} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems';
import './Navbar.css'
import { Button } from '../Button'
import { NavLink as Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class Navbar extends Component {
    state = {
        clicked: false
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({ clicked : !this.state.clicked })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <nav className="NavbarItems">
                <h1 className="navbar-logo">Afrika-Link</h1>
                <div className="menu-icon" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <i className={this.state.clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
                </div>
                <ul className={this.state.clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                                    {item.title}    
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
                <Button>Sign Up</Button>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

Home.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Home</p>
    );
  }
}

export default Home
```

(The sections until now all look like this, so there's only minimal content to check if they get displayed or not)

MenuItems.js:

```js
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        url: '../Home/Home',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Blog',
        url: '../Blog/Blog',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'About',
        url: '../About/About',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Sign up',
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
    }
]
```

I already tried to substitute the `a` with `href` in `Navbar.js` with `Link` but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

- `react-router-dom@6` `Route` components render their content on the `element` prop. The `element` prop takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.
- The routes rendered and the links to them should agree on path.
- The `Navbar` component should render RRD `Link` components instead of raw anchor `<a>` tags. The link target path is specified on the `to` prop.

## A Suggested Solution

App.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar'
import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Blog from './components/Blog/Blog'
import About from './components/About/About'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />

          {/* Redirect all unhandled paths to home page */}
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

menuItems.js

```js
export const menuItems = [
  {
    title: 'Home',
    url: '/home',
    cName: 'nav-links'
  },
  {
    title: 'Blog',
    url: '/blog',
    cName: 'nav-links'
  },
  {
    title: 'About',
    url: '/about',
    cName: 'nav-links'
  },
  {
    title: 'Sign up',
    url: '#',
    cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
  }
];
```

Navbar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems';
import './Navbar.css'
import { Button } from '../Button'
import { NavLink as Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navbar = () => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClicked(clicked => !clicked);
  }

  return (
    <nav className="NavbarItems">
      <h1 className="navbar-logo">Afrika-Link</h1>
      <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
        <i className={clicked ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
      </div>
      <ul className={clicked ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
        {MenuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            <Link className={item.cName} to={item.url}>
              {item.title}    
            </Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Button>Sign Up</Button>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's now working, but to be honest I'm not sure I really understand why it's working. The path in MenuItems.js is now wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @IhoneyIbadger Well, you could keep the routes and link paths as the longer `"/components/Home/Home"` but this seems rather odd. The route paths don't need to match/follow any internal app directory/file structure/organization.

Comment: Ah okay I see, so the components are only linked using the 'element'-tag?

Comment: @IhoneyIbadger Essentially, yes. RRD takes the current URL pathname and renders whatever route's content matched by the route's path. These are arbitrary and independent of any underlying file structure. In other words, you are just mapping the URL pathname to a React component you want rendered.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And how are the 'Route'-elements connected to the Navbar-Buttons?

Comment: @IhoneyIbadger Via the URL path they link/navigate to. They navigate to a path, the router "sees" the updated URL path and then rerenders the appropriate route by matched path. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `Route`'s `path` to the `url` in the array. Make sure it matches.

```
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        url: '/components/Home/Home',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Blog',
        url: '/components/Blog/Blog',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'About',
        url: '/components/About/About',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Sign up',
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
    }
]
```

and convert your `<a href="" />` back to `<Link />`

```
<li key={index}>
  <Link className={item.cName} to={item.url}>
    {item.title}
  </Link>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help. The paths should be correct although they are different because App.js is in 'src' and Home.js is located in 'src/components/Home'. I also exchanged <a> for <Link>

Comment: Can you please produce a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following Solution might help you :

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' component={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/blog' component={<Blog />} >
        <Route path='/about' component={<About />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**MenuItems.js**

```
export const MenuItems = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        url: '/home',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Blog',
        url: '/blog',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'About',
        url: '/about',
        cName: 'nav-links'
    },
    {
        title: 'Sign up',
        url: '#',
        cName: 'nav-links-mobile'
    }
]
```